# Delet data froma a table after certain time interval. lets say (60 mins)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete data from a table after a time interval has been passed and fill it with NULL value. I basically want that data to get expired after a certain interval of time. Is there any way to do it using Php. database is in Mysql.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for some kind of [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to run every minute.

Why do you want to fill in `null` values? It would be best to have `smallint(1)` field that you fill with 1 if the row is deleted. That way you'll always be able to retrieve 'deleted' data if necessary.

Comment: I want that data to get expired after certain interval of time. i dont want to delete the entire row, just the data in that column against the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` field to track how old the record is, and a cron job to delete old records.

Comment: Hi, i am a beginner in php. Will you please explain it to me by using a sample code and how it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html).

Query can be something like this:

```
UPDATE `your_table` SET `your_table_column` = NULL WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try adding another column which says

> expiry_time

(here you add 60 mins to the created date)

And when you are checking for the expiry, check against this column

I dont know about your exact issue, but this might come in handy